# React-router best practice to get nested route pathname

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have a React route like code below:

```
<Route path='/settings' component={Settings} />
```

And inside Settings component, it has 3 nested routes:

```
 <Route path='/settings/general' component={GeneralSetting} />
 <Route path='/settings/team' component={TeamSetting} />
 <Route path='/settings/email' component={EmailSetting} />
```

So my question is how can I get the nested pathname at most right position (such as '/general', '/email') only **without** the parent route ('/settings'). Currently, I'm using string splitter on location pathname (/settings/general) to achieve this. Are there any best practice for this situation?

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use exact `<Route exact path='/general' component={GeneralSetting} />`

Comment: @Omer, thanks for reply, but I want to go into General Setting by route '/settings/general'.

Comment: mm What you mean here: "only without the parent route ('/settings')." ?

Comment: I mean that I still go to GeneralSettings by '/settings/general' then I get the location.pathname is '/settings/general', I want to get the text '/general' only

Comment: @QuocVanTang what do you want to use the nested pathname for?

Comment: Because I'm using material UI Tabs combine with Switch Route, so I need the nested pathname to indicate the active status

Answer (score 1):

IMO, there are no best practice to get child path in react router. You are using string splitter on location which is fine though. 
If you still need to get child path only you can use params in url instead and render component on based of params like below

`<Route path='/settings/:type' component={Type} />`

In Type (new component to render child) component you can get params like below

`this.props.match.params.type`

that will give you general , team and email value based on your url.

Comment: Thanks for reply, this is also a good approach, but following this we will have a condition render (one of three General, Team, Email) in Type component based on the :type params, right

Comment: Right, there is some trade off